# Magento2.4: how to display products on category page which are below 10$

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3.p1

On the category page, Magento should only fetch products that have prices below 10$. This should be for all category pages all over the site. thanks in advance

Comment: you need to override list block file.

Comment: and apply product condtion there.

Comment: <?php
                if($price= $$block->getProductPrice($_product)<10)
                {
              ?>

Comment: that logic is not working, what i'm doing wrong here, thanks

Comment: you should update product collection. otherwise your pagination does not work.

Comment: it would help you how to update product collection. 
https://github.com/monarch-sp/Customlistpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a observer on the `catalog_block_product_list_collection` event and modify the collection.

events.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_block_product_list_collection">
        <observer name="vendor_product_list_filter" instance="{Vendor}\{Module}\Observer\CatalogProductListCollectionObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

app/code/{Vendor}/{module}/Observer/CatalogProductListCollectionObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CatalogProductListCollectionObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $productCollection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
        $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('price', ['lteq' => 10]);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, its working